# Adding rows, running count, running sum to query results

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with the following ddl.

```
 CREATE TABLE "LEDGER" 
   ("FY" NUMBER, 
    "FP" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "FUND" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "TYPE" VARCHAR2(2 BYTE), 
    "AMT" NUMBER
   )
```

The table contains the following data.

```
REM INSERTING into LEDGER
SET DEFINE OFF;
Insert into LEDGER (FY,FP,FUND,TYPE,AMT) values (15,'03','A','03',1);
Insert into LEDGER (FY,FP,FUND,TYPE,AMT) values (15,'04','A','03',2);
Insert into LEDGER (FY,FP,FUND,TYPE,AMT) values (16,'04','A','03',3);
Insert into LEDGER (FY,FP,FUND,TYPE,AMT) values (12,'05','A','04',6);
```

based on the partition of fy,fp,fund and type I would like to write a query to keep a running count from the beginning of fp(fp though it is a varchar it represents a number in the month. i.E 2 equals february and 3 equals march etc.) to a hard number of 14. So taking a closer look at the data you will notice that in FY 15 the max period is 04 so i must add another 10 periods to my report to get my report to have the full 14 periods. here is the expected output.
[image]

here is what i tried, but I'm just simply stumbling all together on this.

```
WITH    fy_range    AS
(
    SELECT  MIN (fy)  AS min_fy
    ,       MAX (fy)  AS max_fy
    FROM   ledger
),all_fys AS
(
    SELECT  min_fy + LEVEL - 1  AS fy
    FROM    fy_range
    CONNECT BY  LEVEL <= max_fy + 1 - min_fy
)
,all_fps    AS
(
    SELECT  TO_CHAR (LEVEL, 'FM00')  AS fp
    FROM    dual
    CONNECT BY  LEVEL  <= 14  
)   

SELECT 
 FUND
 ,G.TYPE
 ,G.FY
 ,G.FP
 ,LAST_VALUE(G.AMT ignore nulls) OVER (PARTITION BY G.FUND ORDER BY Y.FY P.FP ) AS AMT
 FROM             all_fys   y
 CROSS JOIN       all_fps   p
 LEFT OUTER JOIN LEDGER G PARTITION BY(FUND)
                                  ON   g.fy  = y.fy
                                  AND  g.fp  = p.fp;
```

but I end up with a bunch of nulls and some strange results.

Comment: So what have you attempted?

Comment: @OldProgrammer I added my attempt below the question

Comment: A couple of things I don't understand...  If FP is supposed to be a month (2 = February), then why does it run through 14, and not through 12? Perhaps FY is meant to represent year, and you need the "count" to run through February of the following year? Or what? And the other question, if you need a "running count" partitioned by FY, FP, Fund and Type, why does the count for FY=12 start at the value 10, and then stays constant at 10? That is neither a count, nor a sum, and it doesn't seem to be a "running" count. (I assume you want a running SUM, not COUNT, but you need to explain more anyway)

Comment: @mathguy this is more of an accounting thing of our ERP system. 12 months in a year but 14 periods in a year, because out period 12 or December we brake it up in 3 hence 12-13-14 are all December, They are all the same month. I said running count because the running sum I can figure out, what I can't figure out is how to add the additional periods into my query. for example period 04 is the max period for the year 15 for that partition. But I need to get 14 periods per year in my query with the running sum of the prior periods and year by the partition.

Comment: OK - so you need a running sum. But in your sample data, for FY=12, you have only one row, with AMT=6, how does that become 10 in a running sum? Also for FY=15, you have the amounts 1 and 2, so the running counts are 1, 3, 3, 3, ...  but in your sample output you show 1, 2, 3, 3, ... Why 2 and not 3 for the **second** running sum? Your "desired output" must match the sample input and your requirement rules, otherwise everything is very confusing. If the "desired output" is incorrect, please edit your post to make it right.

Comment: @mathguy thanks for pointing it out. I apologize for my mistake you are right about fy 12 I have adjusted the sample output. In addition I fixed the error with 1,3,3,3, again my fault in conceptualizing. I apologize.

Comment: Do you need to fix it also for FY=16? The only row has AMT=3, but your running sums are all equal to 6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the most efficient solution, but it is easy to understand and maintain. First (in the most deeply nested subquery) we find the min `FP` for each combination of `FY`, `FUND` and `TYPE`. Then we use a `CONNECT BY` query to fill all the `FP` for all `FY, FUND, TYPE` combinations (up to the hard upper limit of `14`). Then we left-outer-join to the original data in the `LEDGER` table. So far we **densified** the data. In the final query (the join) we also add the column for the cumulative sum - that part is easy after we densified the data.

`TYPE` is an Oracle keyword, so it is probably best not to use it as a column name. It is also best not to use double-quoted table and column names (I had to use upper case everywhere because of that). I also made sure to convert from `varchar2` to `number` and back to `varchar2` - we shouldn't rely on implicit conversions.

```
select S.FY, to_char(S.FP, 'FM09') as FP, S.FUND, S.TYPE,
       sum(L.AMT) over (partition by S.FY, S.FUND, S.TYPE order by S.FP) as CUMULATIVE_AMT
from   (
         select FY, MIN_FP + level - 1 as FP, FUND, TYPE
         from   (
                  select   FY, min(to_number(FP)) as MIN_FP, FUND, TYPE
                  from     LEDGER
                  group by FY, FUND, TYPE
                )
         connect by level <= 15 - MIN_FP
             and prior FY   = FY
             and prior FUND = FUND
             and prior TYPE = TYPE
             and prior sys_guid() is not null
       ) S left outer join LEDGER L 
           on S.FY = L.FY and S.FP = L.FP and S.FUND = L.FUND and S.TYPE = L.TYPE
;
```

**Output**:

```
FY FP  FUND TYPE CUMULATIVE_AMT
--- --- ---- ---- --------------
 12 05  A    04                6
 12 06  A    04                6
 12 07  A    04                6
 12 08  A    04                6
 12 09  A    04                6
 12 10  A    04                6
 12 11  A    04                6
 12 12  A    04                6
 12 13  A    04                6
 12 14  A    04                6
 15 03  A    03                1
 15 04  A    03                3
 15 05  A    03                3
 15 06  A    03                3
 15 07  A    03                3
 15 08  A    03                3
 15 09  A    03                3
 15 10  A    03                3
 15 11  A    03                3
 15 12  A    03                3
 15 13  A    03                3
 15 14  A    03                3
 16 04  A    03                3
 16 05  A    03                3
 16 06  A    03                3
 16 07  A    03                3
 16 08  A    03                3
 16 09  A    03                3
 16 10  A    03                3
 16 11  A    03                3
 16 12  A    03                3
 16 13  A    03                3
 16 14  A    03                3
```

Comment: great explanation! I have been stuck for days trying to flush this out! Thanks a million for this answer!

Comment: hopefully you are still looking at this question. There is one small issue in FY16 I dont see period 1-4 on the output. I've been trying to adjust it but I'm not getting anywhere, any Ideas?

Comment: @Miguel - I don't understand. Your explanation, as well as your own "desired results" table, show that for each combination of FY, FUND and TYPE, the results will include FP only from the lowest value to the hard coded value of 14. For FY=12, your data has only one row, with FP=05, so the values will be FP from 05 to 14 - why do you need 01 to 04? (Did the requirement change? Or was it wrong to begin with? And if so, it is the same, anyway, for 15 and 16, why just for 12?)

Comment: requirements didn't change if you look at the image for fund= 'A', type='3' you'll notice fy 16 begins with fp 1 since is carrying the previous year sum. Again my apologies for the confusion. I'm simply asking if you can help me figured it out otherwise no worries I'll take another route.